# Tor browser, new IP not working?

Tags: python, selenium, tor

I am trying to use tor browser, and get a new IP address each URL I visit in python.  I am able to open an instance of selenium running the tor browser, but how can I request a new IP every website I visit?

```
binary = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
if os.path.exists(binary) is False:
    raise ValueError("The binary path to Tor firefox does not exist.")
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)


browser = None
def get_browser(binary=None):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    return browser
if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary)
    urls = (
        ('tor browser check', 'https://check.torproject.org/'),
        ('ip checker', 'http://icanhazip.com')
    )
    for url_name, url in urls:
        print "getting", url_name, "at", url
        browser.get(url)
```

Answer (score 2):

To use Python to request a new IP for every request, you need to open a connection to the [ControlPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ControlPort) and issue a NEWNYM signal.

You can use Stem to simplify the connection and commands:

```
from stem.control import Controller
from stem import Signal

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate('password')  # provide the password here if you set one

    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM) # switch to clean circuits
```

Keep in mind Tor may rate limit `NEWNYM` requests so you may need to wait a short while (default 10 seconds) before issuing that command.  Also, due to the limited number of exit nodes, your circuits might get the same exit node depending on how many requests you are issuing.

You need to issue this command every time you want to get a new IP (switch circuits).